# Button functionality with graphic

Tags: php, html

I have a USEMAP with the area/ Coords however that uses an href. How can I get the functionality the buttons used to have with a graphic, where it uses a method=post?

This code makes a directional square, up, down, north, east, west, South, out, reset, and DM.  ( ugess I didn't include the DM and reset code, but I think you get the idea of what I'm going after here.

What I'm trying to do is replace this with is a graphic of a compass.  With a usemap, that maps the coordinates of north, south, east, west.  I'll figure out what to do about up down, out, DM, and reset.

See, with Buttons, you get a nice Name/Value pair that you can assign a value to, but with the imagemap, you only seem to get just the href - with a url, and no way to assign a value to a name for it to decode once you go to that url.

[The North, East West South Up Down Out Reset & DM button Square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU4Sp.jpg)

```
echo "<TABLE>";
echo "<TABLE BORDER=3 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>";
echo "<TR>";
echo "<FORM enctype='multipart/form-data' action='bddmain.php' method='post'>";

//  == Up ==
if ($room->up > 0) 
{   echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGH=CENTER><input type=submit name='dir' value='up' style='width:100%' id='hyperlink-style-button'/></TD> "; }
else        
{   echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><p style='color:grey'>Up</p></TD>";  }

// ==  NORTH  ==
if ($room->north > 0) 
{    echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><input type=submit name='dir' value='north' style='width:100%' id='hyperlink-style-button'/></TD> "; }
else
{ echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><p style='color:grey'>North</p></TD>";  }

echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><input type=submit name='dir' value='reset' style='width:100%' id='hyperlink-style-button'/></TD> ";


echo "</TR> ";
echo "<TR> ";
echo "<FORM enctype='multipart/form-data' action='bddmain.php' method='post'>";

// ==  WEST  ==
if ($room->west > 0) 
{    echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><input type=submit name='dir' value='west' style='width:100%' id='hyperlink-style-button'/></TD> "; }
else
{ echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><p style='color:grey'>West</p></TD>";  }

if ($mycharacter->id <= 5)
    {
     echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><input type='submit' name='dir' value='*DM*' style='width:100%' id='hyperlink-style-button'/></TD>";
     }
  else
    {
     echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><input type='button' action='nothing' style='width:100%' id='hyperlink-style-button'/></TD>";
    }

// ==  EAST ==
if ($room->east > 0) 
{    echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><input type=submit name='dir' value='east' style='width:100%' id='hyperlink-style-button'/></TD> "; }
else
{ echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><p style='color:grey'>east</p></TD>";  }

echo "</TR>";
echo "<TR>";
echo "<FORM enctype='multipart/form-data' action='bddmain.php' method='post'>";

// ==  OUT ==
if ($room->xitout > 0) 
{    echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><input type=submit name='dir' value='out' style='width:100%' id='hyperlink-style-button'/></TD> "; }
else
{ echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><p style='color:grey'>out</p></TD>";  }



// ==  South ==
if ($room->south > 0) 
{    echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><input type=submit name='dir' value='south' style='width:100%' id='hyperlink-style-button'/></TD> "; }
else
{ echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><p style='color:grey'>South</p></TD>";  }



// ==  Down ==
if ($room->down > 0) 
{    echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><input type=submit name='dir' value='down' style='width:100%' id='hyperlink-style-button'/></TD> "; }
else
{ echo "<TD HEIGHT=30 WIDTH=85 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER><p style='color:grey'>Down</p></TD>";  }
```

Comment: If you could show some of your source code that would be a start

Comment: Welcome to SO!, please explain more about your case with codes/pictures or and explanation